# How to set cookies to = 0 after rebirth

Tags: javascript, html

This is a cookie clicker game and I want when you rebirth to have cookies be put back down to zero. I think I'm just formatting this incorrectly.

I've tried using cookies = 0; in my function but it's not working correctly

This is my JavaScript

```
var cookies = window.parent.loadAsNumber("cookies");
document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;

function cookieClick() {
    cookies = cookies + Strength;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
    checkCursor()
    window.parent.saveDefault("cookies", cookies);
 }
///var UP_INTERVAL = 1000; 
///setInterval(cookieClick, UP_INTERVAL);  



 var rebirths = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var ManaPoints = 0;
var SkillPoints = 0;
var Strength = 1;

function buyRebirth() {
var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
if (cookies >= rebirthCost && rebirths < 1) {
    cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
    SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
    rebirths = rebirths + 1;
    document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
    document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
    document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
}
if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
    if (rebirths >= 1) {
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
        cookies = 0;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;

         cookies = 0;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        window.parent.saveDefault("cookies", cookies);
    }
var nextCost5 = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
document.getElementById('rebirthCost').innerHTML = nextCost5;

}
```

HTML:

```
 </head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>

        <body>
            <style>
                div,
                a {
                    text-align: center;
                }

            </style>
            <span id="cookies">0</span>
            <br />
            <span id="rebirths">0</span>
            <br />
            <button onclick="cookieClick()">Click Me!</button>
            <br />
            Cost: 10mp <button id="BigClickBtn" 
 onclick="Bigclick()">BigClick</button>
            <br />
               Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button 
id="cursorCostBtn" 
onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button onclick="buyCat()" 
id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button onclick="buyDog()" 
id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button 
 onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button 
onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>

<br />
   Skill Tree &nbsp; &nbsp; SP:<span id="SkillPoints">0</span>
```

I expect after the rebirth button is pressed for my cookie count to go back down to zero. But the actual output the cookie count doesn't change to zero just takes the price of pressing the button away from the count.

Comment: And what's your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing your app, remember to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> and check the browser's console for errors.

As far as I can tell, we never execute the line that sets the cookie value because the line above it throws an error:

```
document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints; // causes error
// ( There is no html element with id 'SkillPoints' )
cookies = 0;
document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
```

Comment: I do have that I dont understand why i cant get on reset for the counter(cookies ) to go back to zero

Comment: If I comment out the above line where I added `// casues error` it works for me. Keep in mind Cookies has to be higher than rebirth cost and on at least the second rebirth to hit your 'cookies = 0' line

Comment: I got it to work thanks. not sure what i fixed to do it though